# How to truncate a string in .net

Tags: .net

Given the string: `/Projects/Multiply_Amada/MultiplyWeb/Shared/Home.aspx`

I want to remove all trailing characters after the third `/`, such that the result is: `/Projects/Multiply_Amada/`

I would like to do this without using Split or Charindex.

Comment: What do you mean with `without use (Split/Charindex)`? How should a substring be removed without knowing the index where to start?

Comment: Agreed... I thought that was a pretty odd requirement.

Comment: Care to give a reason for your requirements? Otherwise it should be posted on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

OK, your requirements are a bit tough. So, what about this:

```
string RemoveAfterThirdSlash(string str)
{
    return str.Aggregate(
            new {
                sb = new StringBuilder(),
                slashes = 0
            }, (state, c) => new {
                sb = state.slashes >= 3 ? state.sb : state.sb.Append(c),
                slashes = state.slashes + (c == '/' ? 1 : 0)
            }, state => state.sb.ToString()
        );
}

Console.WriteLine(RemoveAfterThirdSlash("/Projects/Multiply_Amada/MultiplyWeb/Shared/Home.aspx"));
```

Comment: how can use aggregate function for string.. it will showing error ('string' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and no extension method 'Aggregate' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)string RemoveAfterThirdSlash(string str)
Line 65:     {
Line 66:         return str.Aggregate(
Line 67:                 new
Line 68:                 {

Comment: Add the System.Linq namespace

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "/Projects/Multiply_Amada/MultiplyWeb/Shared/Home.aspx";

string newStr = str.SubString(0,24);
```

I suppose that answers your question!

Comment: no cant use substring it will affect in server link..so pls give another solution

Answer (score 0):

This code acheives what you need, but I would prefer doing it in 1 lines using the available .NET methods

```
string str = "/Projects/Multiply_Amada/MultiplyWeb/Shared/Home.aspx";

int index = 0;
int slashCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == '/' && slashCount < 3)
    {
        index = i;
        slashCount++;
    }
}

string newString = str.Substring(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are working with paths, you can do this:

```
    Public Function GetPartialPath(ByVal input As String, ByVal depth As Integer) As String

        Dim partialPath As String = input
        Dim directories As New Generic.List(Of String)

        Do Until String.IsNullOrEmpty(partialPath)
            partialPath = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(partialPath)
            directories.Add(partialPath)
        Loop

        If depth > directories.Count Then depth = directories.Count

        Return directories.ElementAt(directories.Count - depth)

    End Function
```

Not tested.